# meaning of "Hold the time warp for your brain"

Tags: meaning

A post says

> Of course, there are millions of exceptions to what I've just said sometimes we do not use an article with a noun that’s a whole other lesson **hold the time warp for your brain**, we're going to stick to these ones. When to use A AN and THE before a noun in a proper English sentence

I understand "time warp" means

> an imaginary distortion of space in relation to time whereby people or objects of one period can be moved to another.

Since, hold often means "hold on", "wait for a short time"

I guess "hold the time warp" means pause that imaginary distortion for a while. Is my understanding right?

Even if my understanding about "hold the time warp" is right, I don't understand the whole piece "old the time warp for your brain", could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you've given doesn't really make sense.

Your understanding is somehow correct.

To me, it means *'keep the question about exceptions in your mind and we're going to focus on these ones (hold it for a later time -- we will explain it later)'.*

Furthermore, it's poorly punctuated. The 3-4 sentences are written as if they were 1 sentence.