# "understanding of" vs. "understanding about"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([meaning of "Hold the time warp for your brain"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/243531/109190)) I said

> Even if my **understanding about** "hold the time warp" is right, I don't understand the whole piece

In [another one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458940/277710) about a technical concept "PPV", I said

> Is my understanding about this correct?

Actually, I am sure whether I use the correct preposition.

[merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understanding) gives these definitions and examples

> : ability to get the meaning of and judge
>
> He lacks an understanding of what's going on.
>
> : an agreement of opinion or feeling
>
> We've come to an understanding about how to proceed.

However, WHO use the word this way

> to improve information and understanding **about** mental illness

where "understanding" seems to refer to some knowledge or meaning rather than an agreement.

When would I use which preposition? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would say _information about mental illness_ and _understanding of_ it, but a sentence where the two phrases are combined with just one preposition is perfectly understandable.